# Notation for list of list of pairs

Tags: notation

If i have ordered list (L) of pairs of two elements  (one element from each set X & Y), how do represent such list? and if i have another list (T) which is list of L, what will be the notation of this? Also, what will the notation to say reject the list Li if last n elements (of type above pair)  of list belongs to any list of T, what will be the notation of this?

Comment: I think your concept of "ordered list" is what a mathematician would call a *tuple* or *sequence*, the latter usually avoided if its length is finite. You may wish to clarify your question based on that.

Comment: @J.G. I would talk about an ordered set of tuples, which highlights a bit more that the individual tupples are similar. Maybe something like $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i\in\{1\ldots N\}}$

Answer (score 0):

I would represent $L$ as an ordered set of tupples, i.e. as $L=\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i\in\{1,\ldots, N\}}$.

Now, I would somehow stop here with representing lists of lists of lists, and simply say something along the line of "Let $\Omega$ be the set of all such ordered sets of tupples, i.e. $\Omega=\{L|L=\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i\in\{1\ldots N\}}\}$". Then go on by simply saying that $T\subset\Omega$. Finally, define the equivalence relation $\approx_N$ by saying that $L_1\approx_N L_2$ if the last $N$ elements of $L_1$ and $L_2$ are equal. Then you can simply say: I reject $Li$ if there exists an $L\in T$ with $Li\approx_N L$.

Comment: "Ordered set" is a bit of a problem.

Comment: @J.G. Not really: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_ordered_set or https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Totally_Ordered_Set